# Can’t get Pico board to run multiple files

Tags: vscode-extensions, raspberry-pi-pico

I am running a MacBook Pro with VSCode and the Pico-W-go extension installed.

Using this extension, I can pick individual files and upload them to the Pico board and they run. However, the latest project is a group of files and no matter what I try, the extension is not uploading the files I have created.

All files are in a folder for the project, but when I select upload Project I get this response

```
Uploading project (main folder)...
Safe booting device... (see settings for more info)

Uploading to / ...
Safe boot failed, 'uploading anyway.
Reading file status
No files to upload
Upload done, resetting board...
OK
```

If I then boot the Pico as a USB drive, I only see these files:

- .fsevented (folder)
- .Spotlight-V100 (folder)
- INDEX.HTML
- INFO_UF2.TXT

I can upload a single file and it runs, but never a project.

I’ve raised a bug on the Pico-W-Go page, but i guess the developer is busy with other work currently.

So I have a number of questions.

How do I upload an entire project? Is there a specific folder structure that is needed?

Also, using buy MacBook, how can I see the files that have been downloaded, even if it is only 12 python script?

I have tried renaming files, lots of searching on Google, checked the USB port is accessible, renaming the files.